# Отдельная JVM для каждой копии апплета

Tags: applet, jvm

Вечер добрый!

Подскажите, при запуске апплета в режиме совместимости (это когда используется не JNLP-загрузчик, а тег <applet> и он встраивается в страниц, а-ля флеш-ролик) наблюдается интересная картина, когда браузеры используют одну копию базового класса, для запуска апплета (одного и того же, естественно) на нескольких закладках. Как следствие забавные вещи вроде единого окна отрисовки и общих статических переменных)

Вопрос, можно ли как-то гарантировать запуск каждой копии апплета в отдельной виртуальной машине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А да. 100 лет назад было...

Общая идея. Идеально, конечно, когда мультиаплетность предусмотрена при проектировании.
Суть очень проста - для каждого экземпляра апплета - будет свой экземпляр базового класса "extends Applet". То есть грамотное наследование и не использование статических объектов (хотя, если вы хотите... к примеру.. кешировать какие-то вещи, которые будут гарантированно однотипными для всех сразу - ну, почему нет) и все будет сухо и уютно.

Но если уж так вышло, что именно так и не получается - то единственным гарантированным выходом будет для каждой страницы, где будет запускаться апплет генерировать рендомную соль в URL'е к сборке апплета. Тогда каждая страница будет тянуть экземпляр апплета заново и он будет гарантированно автономен от всех прочих, в любом браузере.